# Adding Year To FB Timeline Automatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

Does anyone knows, it is possible to add a automatic photo to FB timeline in certain year. For example, I have this app where user click a button, then automatically will post a photo in the year 1983. Does FB allow that to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When publishing to the open graph, you can in fact set the time so that you can post a past event.

There's an official document/toturial for that, part of the [Open Graph docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/): [Publishing Past Actions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/publish-past-actions/).

Hope this is what you're after.

Comment: Yes, that work perfectly..Thanks so much! Now I'm looking for some example on FB to see it in action ;)

Comment: Examples on fb? What do you mean? You can go to your timeline, scroll down as far as you want then hover your mouse over the middle line, the cursor should change to a plus ('+'), click and you are adding an action to a specific time in the past.

Comment: Yes I know that ;) .. I'm talking about apps in FB that would do the automatic post into users timeline.